# Why is my csv to array reading function not working?

Tags: php, csv

I got this great function from another post here on Stackoverflow and it worked well reading csv files into an array. But suddenly it stopped working, probably because the csv format changed. How do I get it working again?

It's:

```
function csvToArray($file) {
    $rows = array();
    $headers = array();
    if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file)) {
        $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $row = fgetcsv($handle, 10240, ',', '"');
            if (empty($headers))
                $headers = $row;
            else if (is_array($row)) {
                array_splice($row, count($headers));
                $rows[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        throw new Exception($file . ' doesn`t exist or is not readable.');
    }
    return $rows;
}

$csv = csvToArray("import.csv");
echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
```

The new CSV format is like this:

```
TITLE,DESCRIPTION,PRICE,CURRENCY_CODE,QUANTITY,TAGS,MATERIALS,IMAGE1,IMAGE2,IMAGE3,IMAGE4,IMAGE5,"VARIATION 1 TYPE","VARIATION 1 NAME","VARIATION 1 VALUES","VARIATION 2 TYPE","VARIATION 2 NAME","VARIATION 2 VALUES"
"Title","Description",10,USD,1,"Category", etc...
```

Some are in quotes, some not but all are coma separated. If the words inside `"Description"` also contain quotes, they are double quoted like `"This is the ""greatest"" description ever"`.

What do I need to change to get this working again? That's so much for any tips!

UPDATE: The error I am getting is this:

`PHP Warning:  array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements`

Comment: The warning message is pretty self-explanatory: `$row` and `$headers` have different number of elements at some point. `array_splice` takes care of cases when `count($row) > count($headers)` so it must be the other way around.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think of that but now that you say it and I counted. The csv data is messed up!

Comment: Ah, I remember having the same problem a long time ago. I seem to remember using [`SplFixedArray`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) to buffer the result from `fgetcsv()`, since you know the theoretical max columns to expect.